# Using normalized X, y after passing through pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using a scikit-learn `Pipeline` to create a SVM. After creating the model, I'd like to use scikit functions like `confusion_matrix`, `plot_confusion_matrix` and `permutation_importance`, in the past when I've used these functions, I've always passed the normalized X values, but when using the pipeline, the values are normalized when the model is fired. Is the pipeline also normalizing these inside of `plot_confusion_matrix` and the like?

Here's the code that includes my `Pipeline` although there's nothing special about it. `num_cols` are the columns in a dataframe that have numeric features and `cat_cols` are categorical features.

```
num_trans = Pipeline(steps=[
            ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
            ('scaler', StandardScaler())])  
cat_trans = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')

#num_cols are numeric features and cat_cols are categorical
preprocess = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
                ('num', num_trans, num_cols),
                ('cat', cat_trans, cat_cols)])          

X = mdf[feats]
y = mdf[tgt].values

model = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocess), 
                        ('classifier', SVC(C=1, gamma=0.1))])
model.fit(X, y)
pred = model.predict(X)[-1]
cm = confusion_matrix(y, model.predict(X))
plot_confusion_matrix(model, X, y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well the question, you are asking if the value in the confusion matrix is also normalized, right?
When you fit the model variable, which is a Pipeline object, you are actually invoking the steps of preprocessing and fitting the SVC classifier.

What *plot_confusion_matrix* is actually doing, is taking your model, do the predictions, compare the true value of the target (stored in y) with the predicted values and generate confusion matrix plot.
*confusion_matrix*, and *plot_confusion_matrix* when invoked **are not launching the fit** method of the Pipeline class, but just obtaining the prediction with the model.predict() method in the class. For this reason, the results in the confusion matrix are not normalized since the functions do not call any fit method in the underlying Sklearn library ([Here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/baf828ca1/sklearn/metrics/_plot/confusion_matrix.py#L443) you can check the source code of plot_confusion_matrix in the Sklearn library). They objective of the Confusion Matrix is obtaining the comparison between predicted and true values of the target.

**NB.**
Looking at the documentation,  plot_confusion_matrix is deprecated in 1.0 and will be removed in 1. I suggest you to use [ConfusionMatrixDisplay](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html)

Comment: The second link read as 404.

Comment: I fixed the link, thank you! [ConfusionMatrixDisplay](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html)

Comment: Thanks @AndreaIerardi but IIUC when you call `model.predict` in my case, it is sending that through the pipe? Is it just that this doesn't work within these ancillary sklearn functions bc of how those are specifically coded?

Comment: @Tom when you call `model.predict` you are not sending it through the pipe but you are just using the method predict of the class Pipeline. You can call a `model.predict` only after you fit (so you after you trained the model) using `model.fit(X,y)`. Here, is when you **send data through the pipe**. Once you trained the model you can use `model.predict`. Sklearn Model and Pipeline works in a similar way. What Pipeline has in addiction, is the possibility of adding more steps before/after you train the mode (i.e. ColumnTransformer). Scikit-learn pipelines are a tool to simplify these processes.

Comment: Very helpful. So in your orig answer, you mentioned that `confusion_matrix` is calling `model.predict`. If `model.fit(X, y)` has previously been called, will `confusion_matrix` work? Or is that function using a separate call to `predict` that results in it not using the pipe?

Comment: If you call `model.fit(X, y)`, the model will be fitted so **you can use** `confusion_matrix` and `plot_ confusion_matrix` methods. If **you do not fit** the model first and you call `confusion_matrix`  then you will get and error.  For what concert the second part of your question *"Or is that function using a separate call to predict that results in it not using the pipe?"*. Yes, when you call `confusion_matrix` you are actually rerunning the `model.predict` since you are passing it as argument. `confusion_matrix` is just comparing the predicted and true values of the target.

Comment: `confusion_matrix` just compare true and predicted values. You doing it since you are passing the predicted values (obtained from model.predict) to the function  `cm = confusion_matrix(y, model.predict(X))`. `plot_confusion_matrix` instead is actually rerunning from the inside a `mode.predict()`  and a `confusion_matrix` to compare true values with predicted ones.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrea is right.

I'd add that if you want to pass the normalized/scaled data to your plot function, you have to transform it using the learned parameters in your Pipeline. Something like below:

```py
#...
model = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocess), 
                        ('classifier', SVC(C=1, gamma=0.1))])
model.fit(X, y)


preprocessor = model.best_estimator_.steps['preprocessor']
X_preprocessed = preprocessor.transform()

plot_confusion_matrix(model, X_preprocessed, y)
```